# Why could I not assign a value to an array directly, instead I had to use .push()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was attempting to solve a problem on codewars but could not use the `.join()` method on my alphabet array because it was undefined with the following code:

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  const alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  let numString = "";
  let countArray = [];

  for (x = 0; x < text.length; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < alphabet.length; y++) {
      if (text[x].toLowerCase() === alphabet[y]) {
        countArray += ++y;
      }
    }
  }
  return numString = countArray.join(" ");
  }
console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

I was then able to solve the problem using the code below:

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  const alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  let numString = "";
  let countArray = [];

  for (x = 0; x < text.length; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < alphabet.length; y++) {
      if (text[x].toLowerCase() === alphabet[y]) {
        countArray.push(++y);
      }
    }
  }
  return numString = countArray.join(" ");
}
console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

I am thinking that the `.join()` method did not work because I was not assigning an index in the `countArray`, whereas push appends to the array which would assign an index automatically?

Comment: The `+=` operator does not add elements to arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `countArray += ++y` because arrays don't work that way in JavaScript like they do in some other languages. That's equivalent to `countArray = countArray + ++y;` which on the first iteration converts the array and the number to strings and concatenates them, assigning the result (a string) to `countArray`. So after that first iteration, `countArray` isn't an array anymore, and has no `join` method. Subsequent iterations are using `+` on a string and a number, and so convert the number to a string and append it to the string. You can see that in action if you log `countArray` at the outset and then on each iteration:

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  const alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  let numString = "";
  let countArray = [];
  console.log(`initial (${typeof countArray}): `, countArray);

  for (x = 0; x < text.length; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < alphabet.length; y++) {
      if (text[x].toLowerCase() === alphabet[y]) {
        countArray += ++y;
        console.log(`x = ${x} (${typeof countArray}): `, countArray);
      }
    }
  }
  return numString = countArray.join(" ");
  }
console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The correct ways to add entries to the end of an array are:

```
countArray.push(++y);
```

or

```
countArray[countArray.length] = ++y;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for ELI5, I feel like I fully understand the concept now